# Subquery containing aggreagate function in Hiveql

Tags: hiveql

Why doesn't this work in Hiveql?

```
create table hist (
   id int,
   state int,
   create_date string);

insert into hist values (1, 1, '2017-01-01');
insert into hist values (1, 1, '2017-02-01');
insert into hist values (1, 1, '2017-03-01');
insert into hist values (1, 2, '2017-02-01');
insert into hist values (1, 2, '2017-03-01');
insert into hist values (1, 2, '2017-04-01');

WITH MonthEnd as
(select to_date(trunc(add_months(current_date, -1), 'MM'))
 MonthEndDate)
SELECT date_add(MAX(a.create_date), 0)
  FROM hist a, monthend me
 where a.create_date <=
 (select max(b.create_date) from hist b
  where a.id=b.id and b.state=2
    and b.create_date < me.MonthEndDate) x
   and a.state=1 and a.create_date < me.MonthEndDate;
```

I would expect an answer of '2017-03-01', but I get this instead:

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 20:24 cannot recognize input near 'select' 'max' '(' in expression specification
```

Side note:  I'm highlighting the bottom select statement in Hue before executing it.  The select statement is in lines 13-17.  There is other commented code after the select query.  Therefore, I have no idea why it's saying the compilation error is on Line 20.

The only StackOverflow question I found close to this recommended I name the subquery.  That's why I added the 'x' after it.  It didn't help.  Same error.

The subquery by itself works:

```
WITH MonthEnd as
(select to_date(trunc(add_months(current_date, -1), 'MM'))
 MonthEndDate)
select max(b.create_date) from hist b, monthend me
 where b.state=2 and b.create_date < me.MonthEndDate;

2017-04-01
```

Thanks in advance for any insight anyone can give here!

Comment: I tried putting the subquery into its own with statement to fool the parser, but now I get an even weirder error:

    WITH MonthEnd as
        (select to_date(trunc(add_months(current_date, -1), 'MM'))
         MonthEndDate)
    select a.id, max_create_date=max(a.create_date) from hist a, MonthEnd b
     where a.state=2 and a.create_date < b.MonthEndDate
      group by a.id;

But now I get this error:

    Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10025]: line 22:13 Expression not in GROUP BY key 'create_date'

Comment: Even adding create_date to the group by clause explicitly (which is not what I want anyway) or using a having clause doesn't resolve the issue.

Does anyone have insight on THIS maybe?

Thanks!!